# Regex: Match group if present otherwise ignore and proceed with other matches

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I have been trying to match a regex pattern within the following data:

String:

> **TestData** to 1colon delimiter list has 1 rows.Set...value is: 1 Save Error: **267467374736437-TestInfo** send Error

Words to match:

> 1. TestData
> 2. 267467374736437-TestInfo

Regex pattern i m using:

```
(.+?\s)?.*(\s\d+-.*?\s)?
```

Scenario here is that 2nd match (267467374736437-TestInfo) can be absent in the string to be matched. So, i want it to be a match if it exists otherwise proceed with other matches. Due to this i added zero or one match quantifier ? to the group pattern above. But then it ignores the 2nd group all together.

If i use the below pattern:

```
`(.+?\s)?.*(\s\d+-.*?\s)`
```

It matches just fine but fails if string "**267467374736437-TestInfo**" from the matching string as it's not having the "?" quantifier.

Please help me understand where is it going wrong.

Comment: That is not going to work. What are the requirements? Try [`^(\S+)(?:(?!\d+-\S).)*(\d+-\S+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/wE6lK5/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew.. I still have to try. I will let you know once done. Thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew.. This worked like charm. Thanks a lot. It's interesting to see the world of negatives. Please let me know how can i up-vote your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather not use a complex regex, which will be ugly and a maintenance nightmare.  Instead, one simple way would be to just split the string and grab the first term, and then use a smart regex to pinpoint the second term.

```
String input = "TestData to 1colon delimiter list has 1 rows.Set...value is: 1 Save Error: 267467374736437-TestInfo send Error";
String first = input.split(" ")[0];
String second = input.replaceAll(".*Save Error:\\s(.*)?\\s", "$1");
```

**Explore the regex:**

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/zQ0rD3/1)

Answer (score 0):

The optional pattern at the end will almost never not be matched if a more generic pattern occurs. In your case, the greedy dot `.*` grabs the whole rest of the line up to the end, and since the last pattern is optional, the regex engine calls it a day and does not try to accommodate any text for it.

If you had a lazy dot `.*?`, the only position where it would work is right after the preceding subpattern, which is rarely the case.

Thus, you can only rely on a tempered greedy token:

```
^(\S+)(?:(?!\d+-\S).)*(\d+-\S+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE6lK5/1).
Or an unrolled version:

```
^(\S+)\D*(?:\d(?!\d*-\S)\D*)*(\d+-\S+)?
```